# TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not HTTPResponse

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a function which fetch a pdf file from an api connection.

My code:

```
label = fk.fetch_labels(oiids)
with open('a.pdf', 'wb') as handle:
    cont = label.raw
    print cont
    handle.write(cont)`
```

fetch_labels :

```
def fetch_labels(self, orderItemIds):
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'}
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/shipments"
    payload = {'orderItemIds':','.join(orderItemIds)}
    return self.session.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload, stream=True)`
```

on running above code it throws error:

```
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f1d8fa24d50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    handle.write(cont)
```

TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not HTTPResponse
`

When i write it to a pdf file using 'wb' it just create a 0 byte file.
whats the correct way.

Comment: If you use `.get(..., stream=True)` you have to use `.read()` on the result to read out the content.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

Comment: I tried that and It says `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @qarma Looks to me like there's nothing about a `.read()` method on the doc page you linked. However there is a [section about streaming requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) that suggests using [the `iter_lines` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation on streaming requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests):

> With requests.Response.iter_lines() you can easily iterate over
>   streaming APIs such as the Twitter Streaming API. Simply set stream to
>   True and iterate over the response with [iter_lines()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_lines)

And thence:

> ```
> iter_lines(chunk_size=512, decode_unicode=None, delimiter=None)
> ```
>
> Iterates over the response data, one line at a time. When `stream=True`
>   is set on the request, this avoids reading the content at once into
>   memory for large responses.
>
> Note This method is not reentrant safe.

So your code would probably use it like:

```
with open('a.pdf', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.writelines(label.iter_lines())
```

Comment: must be string or buffer, not instancemethod.

Comment: I made a typo, there should be parentheses after `iter_lines` because it's a function.

Comment: must be string or buffer, not generator

Comment: Your types aren't correct. Are you using `handle.write` or `handle.writelines`?